# can not search elasticsearch based on document property values

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have lots of product typed documents saved in elasticsearch but couldn't search by documents property values and need help.

```
//Product Class
public Guid productID { get; set; }
public string productName { get; set; }
public Guid productTypeID { get; set; }
public List<Guid> categoryIds {get; set; }
```

I'm trying to search like this:

```
//Search function
var esconn = Yaziylabir.Bukalemun.DataObjects.ElasticSearchConnectionManager.GetClient();
QueryContainer q = null;
if (!ProductType.HasValue || (ProductType.HasValue && ProductType.Value == B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT))
{
    q = Query<ProductModel>.Term(t => t.ProductTypeID, B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT);
}
if (Category != null)
{
    //catListZ is also List<Guid>
    q &= Query<ProductModel>.Terms(u=>u.Field(z=>z.CategoryIDs).Terms<Guid>(catListZ));
}
// as a bonus I also have keyword search
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Keyword))
{
    q &= Query<ProductModel>.QueryString(t => t.Query(Keyword));
}

//do search
var pp = new SearchRequest(Yaziylabir.Bukalemun.DataObjects.ElasticSearchConnectionManager.DefaultIndex, "product");
pp.Query = q;
pp.Size = PageSize;
var res = esconn.Search<ProductModel>(pp);
rtnVal = res.Documents.ToList();
```

Now, I tried combinations of these (only producttypeID, only categoryIDs, only keyword, etc...) and watch what is happening with fiddler.

No result comes back, no errors are raised. Only 0 hits. Request body seems ok too.

When I check documents stored in that index, they are there and they have values required and should return in result.

What is wrong here? Do you have any ideas? Please help me here. I'm feeling ashamed to be the guy who couldn't search a database properly.

**EDIT:**
**Search's body text:**

```
{"size":12,"query":{"term":{"productTypeID":{"value":"cae344cf-8cfa-4960-8387-8ee89899c53f"}}}}
```

**Example document:**

```
{
  "productID": "5687b8ac-c3fe-4f1a-9643-08b0bf6cede8",
  "productName": "7011 Yelek",
  "productCode": "701102Y001  ",
  "currency": {
    "currencyID": 1,
    "sign": "TL",
    "rate": 0
  },
  "normalPrice": 170,
  "currentPrice": 84.9,
  "isDiscounted": true,
  "taxRate": 8,
  "productTypeID": "cae344cf-8cfa-4960-8387-8ee89899c53f",
  "defaultImagePath": "/contents/images/productimages/75681ee4-19b3-4c7d-a24b-b3566085a980.jpg",
  "totalStockCount": 8,
  "totalStockRecordCount": 4,
  "isInStock": true,
  "statusID": "9ad17471-2ff2-4eb0-9cb0-4b86922263ea",
  "categoryIDs": [
    "a8c83f54-b784-4866-89c3-cabc641490d5",
    "9d5a9ab7-8edb-4d5a-800b-c48bf6575d78"
  ]
}
```

I didn't include all properties because it will make document very long.
**Here is the mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "categoryIDs": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "currentPrice": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "isDiscounted": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isInStock": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "normalPrice": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "productCode": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "productID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "productName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "productTypeID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "statusID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "taxRate": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "totalStockCount": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "totalStockRecordCount": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a document you have and the `term` you are searching that you believe it should be returned? Also, it would help to see the mapping of the index.

Comment: As we speak I reindex data, it will take some time because I'm an idiot who didn't use alias. I will edit my question with these details after indexing completed. By the way I rebuild my code with deeper nested usage by this way we will see if I understand when to mark properties nested :-)

Comment: @AndreiStefan I updated the question with example product document and search body text instead of providing just term.

Comment: Can you show the mapping for `productTypeID` field?

Comment: BTW I didn't create mapping manually, elasticsearch automatically created from the class structure I guess. I deleted tons of properties for focusing the problem. If mapping and document I have provided don't have the same structure, it is because of me. I had nested properyties but I couldn't see nested type for these properties too. Do I index wrongly? If you want I can provide the indexing code too.

Comment: I added the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the `productTypeID` field is using either the default analyzer - `standard` - or any other analyzer that's splitting it in the wrong places. What you need is for `productTypeID` to be `index: not_analyzed` or analyzed with something like `keyword`. And you need to create the mapping manually, otherwise you can't do it the way you want it.

The idea is that ES is tokenizing by default your `productTypeID` values and will split them at `-`, so in the index you'd have tokens not the entire value. You, instead, need to have that value unchanged so that `term` will match it fully.

For example, not to mess up with your previous mapping, you can add `fields` to define a sub-field that will be `not_analyzed`:

```
    "productTypeID": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
```

And your query needs to change slightly: `{"size":12,"query":{"term":{"productTypeID.raw":{"value":"cae344cf-8cfa-4960-8387-8ee89899c53f"}}}}`

For completeness sake, this is the complete command to create the mapping by hand. You could do it while the index is still "alive", but you'd still have to re-index the documents:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/your_index" -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "categoryIDs": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "currentPrice": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "isDiscounted": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isInStock": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "normalPrice": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "productCode": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "productID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "productName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "productTypeID": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "statusID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "taxRate": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "totalStockCount": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "totalStockRecordCount": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrei. This is a test environment for me to learn. So I can reindex. If there is a simpler solution, I would like to hear it. Because I will implement the solution all over the code the way I learn. By the way I'm using c# so I'm using nest. I couldn't find attributes like analyzed, etc.. and one more question: couldn't I use auto mapping with providing appropriate attributes?

Comment: That's a longer story. It's about what you need at searching time and depending on that, you can think about what to do with the mapping. Both work together, you can't just index and then struggle with the search because it might not work.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/put-mapping.html: `public string Name { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(OmitNorms = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)]` after a quick google search.

Comment: ElasticProperty attribute is something I couldn't find at the current release of nest. That's actually one of the biggest reasons I'm spending great time here at stackoverflow these days :-)

Instead of ElasticProperty I found another attribute to use but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for: TokenCount.

I try to use it like [Nest.TokenCount(Index = Nest.NonStringIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)] but again I'm not sure if it is and if it is, is it sufficient to use NotAnalyzed alone or should I set another property too.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html#_manual_mapping

Comment: With your help I find out that I wasn't using auto mapping either, now I'm trying to configure my code. After that I will rebuild and try again.

Comment: First I deeply configure all necessary properties with nested attribute, then I reindexed. Of course I also listened you and used not_analyzed attribute property on necessary properties and viola! it works! thank you. I guess my next questions will be more than a newbie! :-)